# What does MOV AL, 0FH mean

Tags: assembly, emu8086

...What does MOV AL, 0FH  mean?

Comment: Moving `0x0F` (15) into `AL`. I'm pretty sure the documentation mentions this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info ... lot of resources.. maybe start with http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moves hex value 0F into the AL register.